# Mark a page of a queried menu as active

Tags: menus, query, css

Im trying to mark as active a page of a queried menu -->
(I found the answer)

```
function render_main_menu(){
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'a_cpt',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'your_tax',
            'field'     => 'slug',
            'terms'     => 'your_term',
        ),
    ),
);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);

$thetitle = strtolower(get_the_title());
$thetitle = preg_replace("/[\s]/", "-", $thetitle);

while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();

    //here the solution--> 
    //marks as bold only the current post -->
    if ( $thetitle == current_post_slug()  ) : ?>

        <div style="font-weight: bold;">

    <?php else : ?>

        <div>

    <?php endif;

    echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a>'; ?>

        </div>

<?php endwhile; 
wp_reset_postdata();

add_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'render_main_menu', 15 );

function current_post_slug() {
    global $post;
    $post_slug=$post->post_name;
    if ( $post_slug && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
        return $post_slug;
    }
}
```

---

thanks

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer, instead of an edit. It's OK to [answer your own question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer), and you can accept it after 48 hours, so the question will not remain open and unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

The code above is correct and includes the answer.
I've added a function with a genesis hook to enwrap it so it should just work with copy-past.